# slick.js carousel not initializing in tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slick.js

slick.js carousel won't initialize in second tab. When I open the second tab the main video does not show until I click the dots.

I tried using $(videoSlider).slick('setPosition'); and also added .each function which does work but not if sliders are in the tabs. If I have numerous carousels on a page they function prooperly. It is only when put in tabs it does not work.

```
 // initialize slick sliders
        $(videoSlider).each(function() {
            $(this).slick({
                arrows: false,
                dots: true,
                infinite: true,
                speed: 500, slidesToShow: 1,
                slidesToScroll: 1
            });
        });
```

Carousel will work in tabs as it does when out of tabs

Answer (score 1):

An issue that stands out is in your selector for `videoSlider`. This needs to be a string value and should most likely be `'.videoSlider'` to match a class used in your markup.

You may also run into an issue if you initialize a slideshow while it's hidden in a tab. In this case, Slick has trouble determining the slide width and assigns a width of '0px' to each slide. You can overcome this issue by refreshing your slideshow when you reveal your tab's contents. For instance, if your slideshow has `id="slideshow1"`:

```
$("#slideshow1").slick("refresh");
```

More information about the hidden slideshow issue: https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/issues/235